# I do not understand this stu[en-11] line of code. How exactly does accessing a structure member work?

Tags: c, arrays, structure

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
struct student
{
    int enroll;
    char name[50];
}stu[2] = {
            {11, "Rj"},
            {12, "Ay"}
            };
int main()
{
    int en;
    printf("Enter Enroll: ");
    scanf("%d", &en);
    if(en==11 || en==12)
    {
        printf("%s", stu[en-11].name);
        printf("\t%d", stu[en-11].enroll);
    }
    else
        printf("Wrong");
    return 0;
}
```

`stu[2]` is an array of structure so generally I should use a for loop for accessing each members of structure, or something like this `stu[0].name`, `stu[1].name`, but in this code below I can also access members using `stu[en-11]`. Please help. How does this work?

Comment: Question: What if I enter 5?

Comment: you will get message Wrong

Comment: @Raj that is incorrect. `5<=12` so it won't go into the `else`

Comment: Thanks @Flikk and sourav I got it and i edited that one. Now, I am still left with stu[en-11]

Answer (score 1):

The correct index for `stu` in your case is 0 and 1.

So, the `en` value has to be either 11 or 12 to get the valid access. You'll be needing the OR operator `||` instead of the AND operator `&&`.

Change

```
  if(en==11 && en==12)
```

to

```
 if(en==11 || en==12)
```

---

Coming to the `stu[en-11]` part, as you've asked, the index value has to be an `int`, and the expression `en-11` produces an `int`. That's all.

Comment: I have one more question. as you can see there is ' - ' sign between en-11 so is this indicate something ?

Comment: @Raj that's a subtraction. :) like 12 - 11 = 1, 11- 11 =0....

Comment: Great! This was the real problem. I thought  it is something special rather than subtraction. Now everything is neat and clean. Thanks

Comment: FYI: Rolled back to rev 1, because the question was changed, making your answer obsolete. Please check question if you have to adopt your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can access both elements by entering 11 or 12 because:

So here is your array:

```
stu[2] = {
        {11, "Rj"},
        {12, "Ay"}
        };

en = 11;
printf("%s", stu[en-11].name); //stu[11-11] is stu[0] (the first element in your array)

en = 12;
printf("%s", stu[en-11].name); //stu[12-11] is stu[1] (the second element in your array)
```

But you have a big problem with your `if (en <= 12)`. If you enter anything lower then 11, you will calculate a invalid index for your array.

Comment: FYI: Rolled back to rev 1, because the question was changed, making your answer obsolete. Please check question if you have to adopt your answer.